# How Retrieving a full tree data in Django Self Foreign Key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I insert 3 records

```
Electronics Null
Mobile 1
Iphone 2

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

if i search Iphone how to get all related data

Example:

```
Category.object.filter(name='Iphone')
```

Result want all parent data
ex:

```
Electronics
Mobile
Iphone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function on the Category model.

```
def get_parents(self, parents=None):
  if not parents:
    parents = []
  if self.parent:
    parents.append(self.parent)
    return get_parents(self.parent, parents)
  else:
    return parents

iphone = Category.objects.get(name='Iphone')
parents = iphone.get_parents()
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimize database queries you need to modernize your model

- [Install django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)
- Change model

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

- Get ancestors

```
from .models import Category

Category.object.filter(name='Iphone').get_ancestors(include_self=True)
```